# Token invalid - Invalid token: Invalid user for the two legged OAuth

Tags: java, oauth, gdata

I am trying to access to google docs using OAuth2.0. I have got the client ID and secret key from Google API console. But When I am running this code, I am getting the exception. can you anyone suggest me if I am missing anything..

```
String CONSUMER_KEY = ".....apps.googleusercontent.com";
        String CONSUMER_SECRET = "sM52Mts_d7snVIomnJaQkjkA";

        GoogleOAuthParameters oauthParameters = new GoogleOAuthParameters();
        oauthParameters.setOAuthConsumerKey(CONSUMER_KEY);
        oauthParameters.setOAuthConsumerSecret(CONSUMER_SECRET);

        DocsService client = new DocsService("testing");
        client.setOAuthCredentials(oauthParameters, new OAuthHmacSha1Signer());

        // Retrieve user's list of Google Docs
        String user = "xesunny@gmail.com";
        URL feedUrl = new URL("https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full" +
                              "?xoauth_requestor_id=" + user);

        DocumentListFeed resultFeed = client.getFeed(feedUrl, DocumentListFeed.class);
        for (DocumentListEntry entry : resultFeed.getEntries()) {
          System.out.println(entry.getTitle().getPlainText());
        }
```

Exception:

```
com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException: Token invalid - Invalid token: Invalid user for the two legged OAuth
```

Token invalid - Invalid token: Invalid user for the two legged OAuth

## Token invalid - Invalid token: Invalid user for the two legged OAuth

### Error 401

Answer (score 1):

The `xoauth_requestor_id` parameter is only for 2-legged Oauth (2LO) which is used to authenticate Google Apps users. I don't think it is possible to authenticate regular gmail users using 2LO.

Have you seen the example for 3-legged Oauth here http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/auth/oauth.html#Examples

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using a Client ID that isn't a service account. Two legged auth is only supported on service accounts. If you create a new service account and use its client ID and secret (an RSA private key), your code should work.